# SQL Group By? Needing a sub select?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking to find all groups that have users that are both registered and unregistered. I was trying to use a Group By but i'm missing something. Thanks

```
Select U.IsRegistered, UG.UserGroupId
From tblGroup G
Join tblUserGroup UG on UG.GroupId = G.GroupId
Join tblUser U on U.UserId = UG.GroupId
Group By U.IsRegistered, UG.UserGroupId

tblUser
-------+----------+-------------
UserId | UserName | IsRegistered
1      | Bob      | 1
2      | Sally    | 0
3      | Jeff     | 1


tblGroup
--------+----------
GroupId | GroupName
1       | Blue
2       | Green


tblUserGroup
------------+---------+-------
UserGroupId | GroupId | UserId
1           | 1       | 1
2           | 1       | 2
3           | 2       | 3
```

Comment: I recommend you look at EXISTS: `where exists (select ... where IsRegistered=1) and exists (select ... where IsRegistered=0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using `group by` and `having`:

```
Select U.IsRegistered, UG.UserGroupId
From tblUserGroup UG Join
     tblUser U
     on U.UserId = UG.GroupId
Group By UG.UserGroupId
Having sum(IsRegistered) > 0 and sum(1 - IsRegistered) > 0;
```

The `having` clause simply specifies that there is at least one registered user and one non-registered user.

Note that the `tblGroup` is not needed in the query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT GroupName
From tblGroup G
Join tblUserGroup UG on UG.GroupId = G.GroupId
Join tblUser U on U.UserId = UG.UserID
GROUP BY GroupName
HAVING AVG(cast(IsRegistered as float)) < 1
AND AVG(cast(IsRegistered as float)) > 0
```

Comment: If the IsRegistered column is of datatype BIT, which I assume it is then this won't work and will error.  Personally I wouldn't find it easily readable either.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding this correctly, we have two conditions that need to be met.First, we need to know that the group has an unregistered user. Second, we need to know that the group has a registered user. So, if we create a statement that has the first condition and inner join that with a statement that has the second condition, that would leave us with only the desired groups.

```
Select UnRegistered_Group.UserGroupId
From (
    SELECT UG.UserGroupID
    FROM tblGroup G
    INNER Join tblUserGroup UG on UG.GroupId = G.GroupId
    INNER Join tblUser U on U.UserId = UG.GroupId
    WHERE U.IsRegistered = 0
) AS UnRegistered_Group
Inner Join (
    SELECT UG.UserGroupID
    FROM tblGroup G
    INNER Join tblUserGroup UG on UG.GroupId = G.GroupId
    INNER Join tblUser U on U.UserId = UG.GroupId
    WHERE U.IsRegistered = 1
) AS Registered_Group
On UnRegistered_Group.UserGroupID = Registered_Group.UserGroupID;
```